# Camel SpringBoot rest servlet connection refused (camel 2.22.0)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, apache-camel

I'm having troubles getting any of the simplest springboot servlet rest api examples to work on my machine. I'm just trying to create the simplest possible test api to practice the framework. I have the following code in my `Routes` `RouteBuilder` class:

```
@Component
public class Routes extends RouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure() {
    restConfiguration()//Bind the api servlet to the localhost port 8080
        .component("servlet").host("localhost").port(8080)
        .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

    rest("/api")//Log any get requests
    .get()
    .route().to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true");

}
}
```

However, when I try to invoke this code with curl, I get the following error:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

I'm using camel 2.22.0 and SpringBoot 2.0.4.RELEASE. I'm running this on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

EDIT:
I did the changes suggested, but I still get the same `Connection refused` by curl. My code now looks like this:

```
restConfiguration()//Bind the api servlet to the localhost port 8080
    .component("servlet").host("localhost").port(8080)//Use camel default context path
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

    rest("/api")//Log any get requests
    .get()
    .route().to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true");
```

`curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/camel/api -> Connection refused`

I also now have the following in my application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8080 #Specify port for camel servlet
  max-http-header-size: 32768 # Maximum size in bytes of the HTTP message header.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Camel uses the context path `/camel/*`.

So, your `curl` command should look like this:

```sh
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/camel/api
```

You can control the context path in the following ways.

With  `restConfiguration`

```java
restConfiguration()//Bind the api servlet to the localhost port 8080
   .component("servlet").host("localhost").port(8080)
    .contextPath("/test/*")
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);
```

With `application.properties`

```
camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path=/test/*
```

**For me, only the latter works.**

Something worth mentioning here.

You are using the `servlet` component in your rest definition. In this case, Camel ignores the `port` configuration and uses the underlying servlet component. As you are using spring-boot, the tomcat port is being used, which by default happens to be 8080.

If for some reason, you change the tomcat port, your rest service port will change.

For example, if you change the server port in the `application.properties`.

```
server.port=8180
```

Your rest service uses that port, ignoring the definition in the `restConfiguration`.

```sh
curl -X GET http://localhost:8180/camel/api
```

Rest DSL [docs](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/rest-dsl.html)

Comment: Okay, would seem valid, but I did these changes and rebuilt the application but I still get connection refused on 8080 even if I specify that in my application.yml file. Adding the modified code to my edit.

Comment: Also I think if the server was even listening on the port, it should just return a error message, rather than refuse the connection?

Comment: Yes, You are right... at least an error message.

Comment: I just noticed that I do not have a `camel-rest-starter` package set up in maven, I tried to add that as a dependency, but it fails with message, that it cannot be found: `Failure to find org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-rest-starter:jar:2.22.0 in https:...`

Comment: I use this dependencies: `camel-spring-boot-starter` and `camel-servlet-starter`. I created this [repo](https://github.com/victordumas/rest-dsl-test) as an example